# IntentFilter -url pattern

Tags: android, intentfilter

Am using intent filter for url based filtering but the pattern is not working as expected (http://www.xyzmobile.com/article/123213  )

The current intent filter is listed down. The main  issue is that i couldn't hard code the entire url because the last portion is dynamic one.

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="@string/deep_host_name"
                    android:mimeType="*/*" 
                    android:pathPattern="/article/.*"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: show where @string/deep_host_name is defined. but looks as it should work - you can remove android:mimeType="*/*"

Comment: This the value of that constant www.xyzmobile.com

Comment: then this looks as it is supposed to work - doing simmilar in own projects - https://github.com/ligi/PassAndroid/blob/master/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L42
you might want to try intent-intercept to debug your issues